# Why do I get : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, tomcat

I am running a web-application on Tomcat. The application uses a video clip to capture some data. Video clip is played and we perform certain actions/operations within the application based upon the activities in video.

But I often get an error on chrome's console(I am using google chrome) which says, failed to load resource - content length mismatch.

[image]

What could be the reason for this? I have been able to play the video for a maximum of 10 minutes.

**PS: It works fine in Firefox**

Comment: have you checked that the server is sending out a correct content length in the content-length header

Comment: @PatrickEvans Is it something that could be configured? Also, will it vary for different items like image/audio?

Comment: If there was a way we could catch the error in javascript, we could reload the media and then set the currentTime to the actual currentTime just before it errored out.

Comment: in my case in laravel i just restart and **refresh** the page.